# How can I alleviate timing/AJAX woes using Capybara/Capybara Webkit/RSpec click_button and page.select?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, rspec-rails

For the sake of simplicity, I've left out most of my test and only included the offending code. It is:

```
click_button('Search')  
page.select 'Preferred', :from => 'ticket_service_type'
```

When I run this, I receive the following:

```
Failure/Error: page.select 'Preferred', :from => 'ticket_service_type'
Capybara::ElementNotFound:
  cannot select option, no select box with id, name, or label 'ticket_service_type' found`
```

The AJAX request this button click event triggers doesn't have anything to do with the select tag, so reversing the order in the test causes the test to pass. I know that Capybara's default wait time is 2 seconds and so I changed it to 10 with:

```
Capybara.default_wait_time = 10
```

This does not cause the test to pass. How can I get these two methods to play nice with one another and work in the order in which a user would operate the web page?

(Had I posted the code from my spec, I bet this would have been solved quickly.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure to add `:js => true` to integration tests which depend upon JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

From [The Cucumber Book](http://pragprog.com/book/hwcuc/the-cucumber-book) (emphasis mine):

> Luckily, Capybara knows how to deal with this situation in a simple way. **If we add an explicit call to find, passing a CSS selector for a DOM element on the page that doesn’t yet exist, Capybara will wait a little (50ms) and try again until the element appears.** If it doesn’t appear after a while (two seconds by default, though this is configurable), it will raise an exception, causing the step definition to fail.

So have your AJAX write something to the DOM then find() it in your step definition.  It's not ideal.  In my case I'm introducing a (hidden) DOM element just to facilitate testing but I haven't found another way.

Comment: I think perhaps you're not picking up what I'm throwing down. ;-)  The assertion has nothing to do with this AJAX request. When the page loads, the element is present and the assertion that it exists passes. After the button-click is initiated inside the spec, an assertion finding the same element will never pass. Nor will any subsequent assertions. That is my dilemma.

Comment: Ya, I'm not picking it up.  Are you saying that #ticket_service_type exists on the page both before and after click_button('Search') -- yet -- page.select fails to find it if you click_button('Search') first?

Comment: That's exactly right, Chris. It's not really all that much fun, to be honest. I can perform the actions as a human and see the results, but testing this thing in a headless manner isn't quite working.

Comment: I haven't run in to the behavior you're describing.  Only two things come to mind, 1) you have @javascript tag on the scenario? and 2) what does the content of save_and_open_page look like after click_button('Search')?  Is in fact the #ticket_service_type element still in the DOM?

Comment: I completely forgot about `save_and_open_page`! Will check that out. Thanks for the reminder, Chris.

Comment: Two things I'd try: 1) comment out all JS code that happens when you click 'Search'.  If that solves the problem, add back in the JS until you find the exact line that causes the problem.  2) change click_button('Search') to something like: page.find("#btn_search").click (this just being a shot in the dark I'd want to try).

Comment: Wow. I had missed the javascript tag in my spec. New spec: http://www.pastie.org/3202056 (line 4 is what a person should focus on, the javascript declaration). Thanks much for the help, @Chris.

Comment: Ah I'm using Cucumber and had asked earlier if you had the @javascript tag on your scenario.  Guess this is the RSpec equivalent.  Glad its sorted out.

Comment: So am I, @Chris. I owe you a beer.