# is it possible to write test for Ajax calls in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

I am learning to write Rails testing in my project.

In my web application most of the sections are loaded using Ajax.

is it possible for me to write Rails testing using any of the gems to test this Ajax calls and its response?

if so consider the below example and suggest me how do i write test and using which gem

- When clicking a button, an ajax call loads time from server. consider the request passed to a url say `/gettime`

thanks,
Balan

Comment: controller specs are there for you

Comment: I believe you would test the javascript with separate tests (and mock the responses), and write functional tests for the controllers. Or you could try to write integration tests which test the combined functionality..

Comment: is that means i cannot really write test for ajax calls directly.. and i should be writing test to test the controller action functionalities?

Answer (score 0):

checkout out this question, it provides a hack that will let you make it work

7193923[ajax timing woes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7193923/how-can-i-alleviate-timing-ajax-woes-using-capybara-capybara-webkit-rspec-click)